# How to set the minimum and maximum coordinates on a cube in three.js?

Tags: three.js

I am making a voxel modeler in *three.js* and I have run into an issue.

When adding cubes to the scene, I set the height, width, or depth, as well as the coordinates to be specific, the cube appears in the center of that coordinate.
For example if I set the coordinates of a cube to 0, 0, 0, then set the width to 1, height to 0.5, and the depth to 1, then the cube will appear to be 0.25 from y of 0 and 0.25 from y of 1.

I have seen topics on getting the minimum and maximum coordinates using Box3 but I need to set them up. Also, using scale won't particularly help in my case, I need to export these coordinates as soon as I am finished with the model.

Comment: you can write a function that takes the min/max values you want and convert them to size and position.

Comment: The issue with this is if I set a function to work one direction, then it wont work another direction.

Comment: The issue with this is if I set a function to work one direction, then it wont work another direction.

Comment: can you show your code?

Answer (score 1):

I have found how to do it now, thanks for your responses! What I did was set the width, height, and depth to the max x, y, z - min x, y, z then set the position to width, height, and depth / 2, then add the min x, y, and z.
This seems to work perfect.

If you wish to see my work so far here is a url:
manassehpierce.github.io